# Photoshop px to usable responsive unit (vw)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am writing a CSS for over a year now and i always have to manually use the simple function to convert PX to VW(Viewport width).
And i would like to add that unit in Photoshop as a default unit, so i don't have to manually read every measurement and calculate it to 'vw' from 'px'.

Comment: One would need to alter the base application code of Photoshop to "add a unit of measure". That's not within the scope of graphic design.

Comment: I don’t get this. How in the world would you imagine that this could ever work? `vw` is a CSS unit that relates to the size of the user’s current browser size – its value changes every time the user resizes their browser. How is a static Photoshop document supposed to relate to an as yet purely hypothetical future user and what size that user’s browser will be in the hypothetical future? Are you sure you understand what `vw` actually means in CSS?

Comment: It's very simple the viewport width would be the PSD canvas width, not really hard to grasp.

Comment: it's very simple, and you would get it if you just take a look at this design/responsiveness 
https://nikoladim123.github.io/property2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your workflow, but I can tell you that it isn't possible to add custom units to Photoshop. I can't really see how Photoshop should know the width of your viewport in a browser and how you distinguish between which measurements to do in px and which to do in vw, but that aside I might have a trick you can use.

In the *Info* panel, click the sandwich menu in the top right corner and choose *Panel Options*.

[image]

Her you can set *Mouse Coordinates > Ruler Units* to *Percent*.

[image]

Now the *Info* panel shows mouse coordinates and selections in percentage of the canvas width and height.

Obviously this only works horizontally, but if you want vertical measurements as percentage of the document's width, you can just change the height of the canvas to the same as the width using *Image > Canvas Size*.

Comment: This is the closest i'll get i guess.
The way i distinguish when to use px and when vw, is mostly always go with vw for both height and with so everything will keep it's proportions only for font size go with calc(12px + Nvw);
And yes percentage are not the best solution for Designs that are long pages and need to convert the height of an object  according to width of the viewport(or in psd case, the canvas width).